# How to choose all 2 elements sub list from the list of 3 elements?

Tags: sage

How to choose all 2 elements sub list from the list of 3 elements?

For example:

`If L=[1,2,3]` I need all the 2 element sub lists `[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]`

Comment: you mean programatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word is [combinations](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/combination.html). Example:

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
Combinations(L, 2).list()
```

Output: `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`